# Javascript why Number and ParseFloat both create a long number when adding up numbers?

Tags: javascript

I'm adding up numbers using Javascript.

I tried using `Number` and `Parsfloat` but the number is returned is strange and long...

```
like 19.0000000
```

A simple working example is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/7kkqkuhw/

and this is my code:

```
$(document).on('click','.btn',function(e){

var price = $(this).attr('data-price');


var curPrice = localStorage.getItem('totalPrice');

var setPrice = Number(price) + Number(curPrice);

alert(setPrice);

});
```

Could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try round() if you don't need decimals

Comment: @JSmith, I do need the decimals.. a normal calculator would add up 15 + 4.99 and returns 19.99 but my code returns 19.000000000.... etc etc....

Comment: [try this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)

Comment: This is a highly relevant page on this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: There is also [*Is floating point math broken?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/7kkqkuhw/2/):

```
$(document).on('click','.btn',function(e){
    var price = $(this).attr('data-price');
    var curPrice = localStorage.getItem('totalPrice');
    var setPrice = Number(price) + Number(curPrice);
    alert(Math.round(setPrice * 100) / 100);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is a problem related to floating point arithmetic and the way computers do calculations on decimal values.

See this related question on Stack Overflow:
[How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

For instance, when you add 0.1 and 0.2, you won't get 0.3 in JavaScript, and in a lot of other languages that support floating point calculations.

```
0.1 + 0.2 == 0.30000000000000004
```

However there are some arithmetic libraries that handle exact arithmetic:

- [Decimal.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/)
- [BigDecimal.js](https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js)

Yet, it is more appropriate to use JSmith's trick:

```
Math.round(value * 100) / 100
```